# Delete blank spaces in a string column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql table with the following values:
'test1 ', 'test2 '.
I need to delete all blank spaces in a string.

It looks easy but TRIM, LTRIM, RTRIM or REPLACE(column,' ','') does not work.

LEN() function count that space as a character.
Lenght of value 'test1 ' is 6.

In which way can I select that column without that blank space?
I need value 'test1'.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: *"LEN() function count that space as a character."* What do you mean by this? As in `LEN(YourColumn)` returns 0? If so that suggests that the column is a `char` or `nchar`. If it's returning a value > 0 for a column you think only contains spaces, then they aren't spaces. They are a different character (and `LTRIM`/`RTRIM` doesn't work on those).

Comment: What does *does not work* actually mean?

Comment: If I copy and paste your example, `'test1 '` and wrap it in `LEN` (`SELECT LEN('test1 ')`) I don't get 6, I get 5. The fact you getting 6, however, indicates as i suspected, the character is **not** a space but something else. What does `UNICODE(RIGHT({Your Column},1))` return for the specific row? Or, alternatively, what does `CONVERT(varbinary(100),{Your Column})` return? (assuming 100 is an appropriate length)

Comment: unicode returns 13

Comment: `13` is a carriage return, not a space, @inspiredd .

Comment: thanks for help. It works now : replace(column1,char(13),'')

Answer (score 0):

The **minimal reproducible example** is not provided.

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.udf_tokenize;
GO

/*
1. All invisible TAB, Carriage Return, and Line Feed characters will be replaced with spaces.
2. Then leading and trailing spaces are removed from the value. 
3. Further, contiguous occurrences of more than one space will be replaced with a single space.
*/
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_tokenize(@input VARCHAR(MAX))
   RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN 
   RETURN (SELECT CAST('<r><![CDATA[' + @input + ' ' + ']]></r>' AS XML).value('(/r/text())[1] cast as xs:token?','VARCHAR(MAX)'));
END
GO

-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @mockTbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), col_1 VARCHAR(100), col_2 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockTbl (col_1, col_2)
VALUES ('  FL   ', '  Miami')
   , ('  FL   ', '  Fort       Lauderdale   ')
   , ('  NY   ', '  New           York   ')
   , ('  NY   ', '')
   , ('  NY   ', NULL);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @mockTbl;

-- remove invisible chars
UPDATE @mockTbl
SET col_1 = dbo.udf_tokenize(col_1)
, col_2 = dbo.udf_tokenize(col_2);

-- after
SELECT *, LEN(col_2) AS [col_2_len] FROM @mockTbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

As discovered in the comments, the character(s) at the end of your value isn't a whitespace, it's a carriage return. `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` don't remove these characters, and `TRIM` only removes whitespace (character 32) by default.

If you want to remove some other characters, you can use `TRIM`, but you need to tell it to remove said other characters, using the `TRIM({Characters} FROM {String})` syntax. The below removes leading and trailing Spaces (`' '`), Carriage Returns (`CHAR(13)`) and Line Breaks (`CHAR(10)`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (SomeString varchar(50));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (SomeString)
VALUES('Trailing Space'),
      ('Trailing Line Break' + CHAR(10)),
      ('Trailing CRLF' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)),
      ('Trailing CRLF and spaces ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '  ');
GO

DECLARE @TrimCharacters varchar(10) = ' ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

SELECT SomeString,
       LEN(SomeString) AS Len,
       DATALENGTH(SomeString) AS DataLength,
       TRIM(SomeString) AS Trimmed,
       DATALENGTH(TRIM(SomeString)) AS TrimmedDataLength,
       TRIM(@TrimCharacters FROm SomeString) AS WellTrimmed,
       DATALENGTH(TRIM(@TrimCharacters FROm SomeString)) AS WellTrimmedDataLength
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below to check if each character of the string is within the ASCII values 32 to 126 (Numbers & Alphabet).
This will remove the "character" that's not within the ASCII range.

**SQL:**

```
DECLARE @TestString varchar(10) = 'test1 '
DECLARE @Result nvarchar(max)
SET @Result = ''
 
DECLARE @character nvarchar(1)
DECLARE @characterposition int
 
SET @characterposition = 1
WHILE @characterposition <= LEN(@TestString)
BEGIN
    SET @character = SUBSTRING(@TestString , @characterposition, 1)
 
    IF ASCII(@character) >= 32 AND ASCII(@character) <= 126
        SET @Result = @Result + @character
    SET @characterposition = @characterposition + 1
END
 
SELECT @Result
```